# composer ps4 is not updating autoload_ps4.php

Tags: php, class, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I am using laravel4 and here is my composer.json file...

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.1.*",
        "iron-io/iron_mq": "1.5.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "psr-4": {
        "iw\\" : "app/iw"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

But its not adding iw// to vendor/autoload_ps4.php and it shows following....

```
<?php

// autoload_psr4.php @generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'Monolog\\' => array($vendorDir . '/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog'),
);
```

Now how is it showing Monolog without referencing it in composer.json...

I have tried running both command `composer update` and `composer dump`.  Really need your help to solve this. thanks

Answer (score 4):

the psr-4 needs to be within the autoload.

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "iw\\" : "app/iw"
    },
},
```

Answer (score -1):

Laravel requires Monolog, so it's getting included in your project.

Each package that your project depends on and that you include via your `composer.json` file might have other packages that they depend on. Those will also be downloaded to your `vendors` folder and included in your autoload file.

Comment: Thanks, but why its not autoloading `"iw\\" : "app/iw"` using psr-4?